# Tuist generate fails with Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, tuist

After updating Xcode to 13.0, I get an error when trying to run the command:
`tuist generate`

**The error:**
The 'swiftc' command exited with error code 1 and message:
error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: framework not found ProjectDescription

This command was working before the update.
I tried updating tuist to the latest version, 1.50, but that doesn't work

Comment: Maybe [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tuist/tuist/issues/3454) is relevant, it might be a better idea to contact the developers instead.

Answer (score 4):

`tuist update` solves the problem